# Base64 String from Bitmap

Tags: c#, string, bitmap, base64

I am reducing the quality of an image and saving it to the file system. I wish to return the new data of the image in Base64 string format. How can I do this?

Code:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(Base64ToImage(base64String));
var jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

var myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, Convert.ToInt64(75L));
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

bitmap.Save(filePath, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

**Update:**

Would the following be an appropriate method?

```
// Convert the image to byte[]
var stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpg);
var imageBytes = stream.ToArray();

// Convert byte[] to Base64 String
var reducedQuality = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
return reducedQuality;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving it to a file, save it to a `MemoryStream`. Then you can use:

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
```

And to write the original binary data to a file:

```
using (var output = File.Create(filePath))
{
    stream.CopyTo(output);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `ToBase64Transform` with a `CryptoStream`:

```
using (var output = new CryptoStream(File.Create(filePath),
                                     new ToBase64Transform())
{
    bitmap.Save(output, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
}
```

That should write it to the file directly *as* base64.

Comment: I need to do both. Save it to the file and get the new Base64 string.

Comment: @Subby: Well if you store it in a `MemoryStream`, you can then write that to disk as well.

Comment: Hmmm, Would your method save an actual Image though and not a file that contains Base64 String? Just to make sure we're on the same ground, I've managed to save an Image to the file system with reduced quality. What i'm trying to achieve now is get the Base64 String of the newly reduced Image and return it.